# Getting a CMD window to fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I use Ubuntu on a regular basis and I'm used to work with the terminal. Now I have to do some work in Windows and the terminal equivalent program there (CMD) opens in a rather small window.

I thought maximizing it would full the screen but it doesn't, the width remains the same. Is there any way to get that window to use all the screen?

If there isn't, does somebody know an alternative terminal program for Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increase the width by using the "layout" options.

> Right click > Properties > Layout

will change the current window

> Right click > Defaults > Layout

will change all subsequent windows.

[image]

Set the Window Size values, though you may have to experiment to get the width (and height) you desire.

Comment: Darn. I never knew this and I have been trying the native windows drag with mouse way (and cursing) all these years.

Comment: @Hennes - it's not exactly obvious.

Comment: Oh, thank you it works like a charm. Although I'd really like to have a fast way to do it, do you know a way to map that to a hotkey or to the maximize button?

Comment: @ChrisF maybe they will make it comparable with the normal windows interface in future versions. Even if only in the name of consistency. :)

Comment: alt-space, x will maximize the window. Also, check out Console2 or ConEm (Console Emulator) as two shell... helpers. They don't replace cmd.exe, but can give it a somewhat different UI.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I will look into them. As for the Alt+Space and X maximizes but doesn't fill the screen.

Comment: Typing <alt-enter> in a console window will also toggle it back and forth between full-screen and a window.

Comment: Links to answers about [ConEmu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) and [Console2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/440370/1405560).

Comment: AltEnter does not works in console and new Win (64bit especially) versions, but it works in ConEmu.